# Gradient Background Problems

Tags: css, gradient

I am currently trying to create a gradient background, and am running into a very annoying problem.  My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Radial Gradient</title>
<style>
body {background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 412 64,  515, 412 59, 40, from(#1a82f7), to(#2F2727), color-stop(.6, #464be8));}
</style>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">


    </div>
</body>




</html>
```

I have tried and tried, and researched more than I care to. And yet, this gradient will not show up radial.  Instead, it shows up with a thick blue line in the center that shows up just left of the center of the screen and expands to a lighter blue.  I need some help with this.  Any advice on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: use `-webkit-radial-gradient(#2F2727,#464be8 60%,#1a82f7)` instead

Comment: So I tried that, and it is still doing the same things, now with just a normal gradient as well.  I tried copying straight from the W3 website and still end up with the same problem.  I don't know how copying would have the same problem.  I am using a Mac and didn't think that would cause any issues.

Comment: try adding the parameter circle, like so: `-webkit-radial-gradient(circle,#2F2727,#464be8 60%,#1a82f7)`

Comment: Trying this still had no fix.  I tried to add the screen shot to this post, but not sure how to do that.  I am really getting frustrated with this.  The result of using this code was a dark line going up and down and slowly turning into blue as it spreads out.

Comment: try aplying the gradient to a different element, and then set the width and height of the element, maybe something like this: 
`div{height:100px;
width:200px;
background:-webkit-radial-gradient(circle,#2F2727,#464be8 60%,#1a82f7);}`.
i tried recreating your code and i get the same problem, unless i set the dimensions of the element.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that worked perfectly.  It is amazing how simple the fix was, just curious why you can't set it to the body, and you can't set an auto for the size.  That's what I love about the online community for Web Design, there are so many knowledgeable people that are willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `radial-gradient` instead of `gradient`: [CSS3 Gradients](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp), more about radial-gradient [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient).